# Execute multiple .py files at the same time

Tags: python, scripting

I have three .py files that I want to run at the same time in a Python script file. I initially called `subprocess.call()` three times (once for each .py file) but remembered that it blocks until the command is finished. I tried `subprocess.Popen(['screen', 'python_file'])` since I believe it doesn't block but when I was checking for the processes with `screen -ls` there was only one process running. How do I get all three programs running at the same time with a Python script? Should I be using the `multiprocessing` or `multithreading` library?

Edit: The other processes aren't supposed to finish since they're running in an infinite loop. Here's exactly what I had in my Python script file. I'm using `screen` because each .py file has stdout logged onto the terminal and I want to be able to see what is being logged for each one.

`subprocess.Popen(['screen', './submitter.py'])`

`subprocess.Popen(['screen', './worker.py'])`

`subprocess.Popen(['screen', './tester.py'])`

Comment: `Popen` already does what you want. If you can see only one process then it simply means that the other processes already finished their work(or maybe they exited due to an error).

Comment: It works for me. Can you show us an example?

Comment: Any reason why you are using 'screen'? Its not needed just to run the files.

Comment: @tdelaney An example of what is being displayed when I run `screen -ls`?

Comment: What you've done works for me. Perhaps the .py files failed. You could create them all in a list, sleep a few seconds and then print out return codes `for p in procs:print p.returncode`. It'll be None if the proc is still running.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks! It worked. It was just a bug on my part that I found.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use `multiprocessing`, you can try this:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(file):
    # your subprocess code


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = ["path/to/file1.py","path/to/file2.py","path/to/file3.py"]
    for i in files:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        p.start()
```

Comment: If a subprocess raises an uncaught exception, what will happen?

Comment: @JordanFeldstein I am not exactly sure what you mean by `uncaught exception`, but here is some documentation on exceptions in `subprocess`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#exceptions

Comment: @enginefree That works! But I need those process come up with different CMD name by 'ps -ef'. Please kindly check up this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362708/run-multiple-python-scripts-concurrently-with-different-cmd-name