# Run multiple python scripts concurrently with different CMD name

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I try to call a.py and b.py concurrently in test.py by multiprocessing.Process(), it worked. But the process **CMD** name of a.py, b.py and test.py, which are '/usr/bin/python /tmp/test.py', are the same .

```
# ps -ef | grep b.py
UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
501 61486 39878   0  2:33PM ??         0:00.05 /usr/bin/python /tmp/test.py
501 61487 61486   0  2:33PM ??         0:00.01 /usr/bin/python /tmp/test.py
501 61488 61486   0  2:33PM ??         0:00.01 /usr/bin/python /tmp/test.py
```

I'd like to have these three processes show different CMD names by 'ps -ef' as below: (which can help me to identify whether different process is running or not.)

```
# ps -ef | grep b.py
UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
501 61486 39878   0  2:33PM ??         0:00.05 /usr/bin/python /tmp/test.py
501 61487 61486   0  2:33PM ??         0:00.01 /usr/bin/python /tmp/a.py
501 61488 61486   0  2:33PM ??         0:00.01 /usr/bin/python /tmp/b.py
```

Please help advice:)

Source code is as below:

test.py:

```
import multiprocessing
import a
import b


p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=a.printa)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=b.printb)

p1.start()
p2.start()
```

a.py:

```
import time


def printa():
    while True:
        print 'a'
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    printa()
```

b.py:

```
import time

def printb():
    while True:
        print 'b'
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    printb()
```

Comment: This is a solution to my question, but it seems a little bit odd by listing lines of **python xxx.py &**. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549641/run-multiple-python-scripts-concurrently

Comment: Use `Subprocess` instead of `Process`

Comment: @stovfl Can `subprocess`  call a specific method of a module? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, simplest case call the`method` beneath of `if __name__ `

Comment: Could you please help explain a little bit more about the solution? Like an example? Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `a.py` and `b.py` as a library in python, therefore it is called under the same name as the executed file `test.py`. Either using `multiprocessing`or `joblib` the same situation occurs.

There is a name option in the `Process` method (`multiprocessing.Process(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={})`), but as @fedterzi says, it is only for identification purposes.

If you want to call a process or file, you can use the library [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Depending on the task you are performing, such as parellelizing a bunch of processes, you could also use [gnu parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) or some other method through `bash` in order to accomplish your desired behavior.

Comment: No, the name of the process won't change the process title, it's just there for identification purposes

Answer (score 0):

Read Python » 2.7.13 Documentation [using-the-subprocess-module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)
Choose from `subprocess` a **NOWAIT** Method, 
edit your Questions code accordingly.

```
import subprocess

def openCmd(name):
    return subprocess.?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        key = raw_input('input 1=open, 0=terminate, q=quit:')
        print(key)
        if key == '1':
            A_p = openCmd(('a'))
            B_p = openCmd(('b'))
        if key == '0':
            A_p.terminate()
            B_p.terminate()
        if key == 'q':
            break
```

***Tested with Python:2.7.9***

Comment: What does 'return subprocess.?' mean? Thanks:)

Comment: @WillZhou: `subprocess.?` is a placeholder. Read the suggested Documentation and choose a Method from the `subprocess` module.